# Получить строку из файла

Tags: php

Ребят подскажите как распарсить файл что бы получить строку
Пример текста:

Текст 
Текст 
Текст 
Текст 
Email: mail.mail@mail.ru
Текст 
Текст 
Текст 
Текст

нужно получить именно эмейл в этом файле, тоесть получить данные после слова "Email:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями. Например, можно отталкиваться от следующего скрипта:

```
<?php
//$str = 'Текст Текст Текст Текст Email: mail.mail@mail.ru Текст Текст Текст Текст ';
$str = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$pattern = '/Email:\s+([^\s]+)\s/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $out);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out[1]);
```

Comment: Спасибо,  с регулярками у меня плохо (

Comment: @cheops чтоб поучаствовать в разговоре :) - `/Email:\s+(\S+)/`

Comment: а если у меня в папке на хосте много файлов их которых нужно выташить эту почту, как проще сдлеать?))

Comment: @lxxnutsxxl, файлы большие? Если их объединить в память скрипта влезет (обычно 128Мб)? В принципе можно циклом обойти, собрать их содержимое в одну большую строку и скормить регулярному выражению.

Comment: 600 штук) общим размером гдето 1.5 мб

Comment: Называються подрят все : 1.txt, 2.txt и т.д.
и потом мне просто их в бд нужно запихнуть

Comment: @cheops так что подскажешь код?

Comment: @lxxnutsxxl В самом простом случае можно пробежаться функцией glob() и сохранить все содержимое в одну строку и потом скормить ее регулярке 
$str = '';
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
  $str .= file_get_contents($filename);
}

Comment: отлично работает)